# Why does useIsMounted return a callback instead of the value itself?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, usecallback

I'm referring to `useIsMounted` from [usehooks-ts](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-is-mounted). I'm trying to understand why the function is returning `useCallback(() => isMounted.current, [])` instead of just `isMounted.current`.

I've tested both ideas in a CodeSandbox that just uses a `setTimeout` to simulate async work and I haven't found any issues returning the value instead of a callback. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason the authors of this `useIsMounted` hook decided to return a function instead of the boolean `isMounted` value. The returned function is memoized so it can be safely passed as a callback to children components.

Returning `isMounted.current` doesn't work though, but returning the entire `isMounted` ref does.

Example:

```
const useIsMounted = () => {
  const isMounted = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;

    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  return isMounted;
}
```

And this requires consumers to know it's a React ref and that they need to unpack the current ref value.

```
function Child() {
  const [data, setData] = useState("loading");
  const isMounted = useIsMounted();

  // simulate an api call and update state
  useEffect(() => {
    void delay(3000).then(() => {
      if (isMounted.current) setData("OK"); // <-- access ref value
    });
  }, [isMounted]);

  return <p>{data}</p>;
}
```

[image: Edit why-does-useismounted-return-a-callback-instead-of-the-value-itself]

Seems it was just a design decision to return a memoized function.